# sails.js restrict global policy in some controller field

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a policy 'sessionAuth' :

```
    module.exports = function (req, res, ok) {
        if(req.session.authenticated && req.session.admin){
            return ok();
        }
        else{
            res.view('admin/login',{'error':"please login first"});
            return;
        }
    };
```

in my config/policies I did :

```
module.exports.policies = {
'*': 'sessionAuth',
  admin:{
    '*':false,
    edit:'sessionAuth',
    'logout':'adminAuth',
    'create':'adminAuth'
  }
}
```

Now I need sessionAuth policy form my all controllers except some field in adminController like login, forgotpassword etc.

but when I did this I'm getting the

> 403 Forbidden

so how to do this any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Admin Controller`'s name is `adminController` so it should be:

```
module.exports.policies = {
  '*' : 'sessionAuth',

  adminController: {
    '*'              : false,
    'edit'           :'sessionAuth',
    'logout'         :'adminAuth',
    'create'         :'adminAuth',
    'login'          : true,
    'forgotpassword' : true
  }

}
```